# sql previous row

Tags: sql

I have a SQL question, typical :previous row, next row question BUT:
NOT USING rownum,lead or rankover these functions, only select and join,

Table: `Student`

Fields: `Student_ID, Department, Start_Date`

ex:

```
1,C, 2017-01-1 
1,B, 2017-07-1 
1,A, 2017-12-1
```

Expected Output:

```
Student_ID, Department, Start_Date, End_Date
```

ex:

```
1,C, 2017-01-1, 2017-07-01 
1,B, 2017-07-1,2017-12-01 
1,A, 2017-12-1, ...
```

End_Date is the start Date of the next record for the student ID

Comment: Which database? SQL Server? Oracle? This particular pattern is pretty well covered. Do you not want to use those functions because your database doesn't support them?

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for replying, SQL server is ok. Not because of support, because it is a interview test restricting without function.

Comment: Why not use `lag()`? That is standard SQL supported by all modern DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

**Data**

```
create table student (
    Student_ID int,
    Department char(1),
    Start_Date date
);
insert into student values (1, 'A', '2017-01-01');
insert into student values (1, 'B', '2017-01-01');
insert into student values (1, 'C', '2017-12-31');
```

**SQL Server**

```
select 
    student_id,
    department,
    start_date,
    (select top 1 start_date 
     from student
     where student_id = s.student_id
     ) as end_date
from student s
order by student_id, department;
```

Example: http://rextester.com/HLL58959

**PostgreSQL and MySQL and SQLite**

```
select 
    student_id,
    department,
    start_date,
    (select start_date
     from student
     where student_id = s.student_id
     limit 1) as end_date
from student s
order by student_id, department;
```

Example: http://rextester.com/XWUAZ90711

Comment: Hi Zed, thank you for your help. However if I switch the department A and C, what should we do instead? Since the data is dummy that I write for sample, but we could make sure that later start time follows larger department

Comment: Can you add the case that you mention to your question and the expected result? I have also added ordering to the query so that A comes first, then B, then C for a given student id

Comment: Sorry, yes I have fixed that, now it is updated. Yes I see that you add limit 1 for mySQL, but if I have to use SQL server, could you advise?

Comment: SQL Server example already has `top 1 start_date` included in the SQL which is similar to MySQL's `limit 1`. In your update case, use the query in my answer and remove `order by student_id, department`